# Craft install failed with error php7 not found, but server has php 7 installed

Tags: craft3, php, installation

I'm trying to install a backup from production site which is running craft 3.0.26 to a UAT site. While installing, faced an error regarding PHP versions. Since both the sites are in the same server, where server shows php71 as the version, but while trying to install craft on UAT site using ssh, its showing error since PHP is running on 5.6.0.

Please help need regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your server environments are different. It is possible to run different version of PHP on different parts of a server, so it really depends on your setup, but that is surely what is going on here. Without more details about your server I don't think it will be possible to give a more detailed answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. The Cloud server is running Plesk with multiple PHP versions. Even though the subdomain I install onto is set to PHP 7.2, SSH comes back as though it is PHP 5 - because SSH is ignoring what the domain is, and only looking at what the server is.